# How in tornado turn on keep_alive explicitly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

How in tornado turn on keep_alive explicitly ? I am using HTTP 1.0 client and tornado doesn't kill incorrectly closed connections and lot off them stays in state ESTABLISHED of(0.00/0/0).

```
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
settings = dict(
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
    cookie_secret="iouoihiohoil]l]lopjiuguyguftyfgvhubjbkjnkm[p[TP1o/",
    xsrf_cookies=False,
    autoescape="xhtml_escape",
)

app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[
             (r"/high_score", handlers.HighScoreHandler),], **settings)

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
http_server.listen(7823)
```

Comment: Why you are not using nginx in front of tornado?

Comment: @NikolayFominyh I am gonna use, but I need something quickly because it is already in productiona and I thought if it is parameter just to restart quickly

Comment: adding front end server will help you much better.

Answer (score 0):

According to [sources](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/httpserver.py) - there are `no_keep_alive` option, which is `False` by default.

You can disable keep-alive, but it's better to use `nginx` in front of tornado. It will help you to support keep-alive for http 1.1 and avoid dead connections for http 1.0..

You can also play with `HTTPConnection` class, but it's more expensive than just adding nginx.